# UISearchController inside UISplitView with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

So I'm using this project as my example of the issue I'm having:
https://github.com/ioscreator/ioscreator/tree/master/IOS8SwiftAddSearchTableViewTutorial

The two changes I make are #1:
make it a universal app

#2 drag a UISplitview controller into Interface Builder and set it as the root view controller with the existing UINavigationController assigned as the detail view segue

Load it on the iPad in portrait and everything is fine because it is only showing one column. If you turn it to landscape though and try again you'll see that the searchbar position is now wrong. I've seen several other related issues that mentioned setting edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None but that appears to be a different issue than this. Has anybody else run into this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know are you using storyboard for setting UISearchBar if YES then set proper constraint to it, so it will show perfect

Comment: I'm adding the UISearchBar in code. I tried messing with adding a constraint but I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with that. This is what I tried adding: override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView.tableHeaderView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.tableView.tableHeaderView!.superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        resultSearchController.searchBar.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
    }

Comment: I suggest try to use storyboard for set object with constraint because as compare to manage it via code it's so simple. Go throw some tutorial I know easily understand it. Apple also recommended use storyboard for set constraint for object not code.

Comment: I don't see any methods on UISearchController to set the searchBar. Everything I've read talks about subclassing which should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the constraints programmatically can be extremely difficult, it depends entirely on the layout of the current view.

Have you tried creating it in storyboard and then setting the hidden value to true on viewDidAppear() and then setting it to false when you need it?

That way you may be able to set the proper constraints using storyboard, then show it when you need it.

Comment: There's no way to add a UISearchController from a Storyboard.